# Создание новой страницы по шаблону (php)

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании материала новостей(либо новой страницы) создавался файл по определенному шаблону?

Comment: Что значит "создавался файл"?

Может, вы имеете ввиду случаи, когда обращение к новости идет по определенному имени, строке? (в таком случае, вам нужен "ЧПУ", роутинг, может)

Или же вы имеете ввиду постраничный вывод, но с единым шаблоном? (в таком случае смотрите "Шаблонизаторы")

Comment: Например есть форма, в которой указывается "заголовок" и "текст". При отправке файл передавался бы обработчику, который в своё время создает новую страницу с расширением .html и с сохраненными в ней данными из формы

Comment: А какой в этом практический смысл? Похоже вам действительно нужен ЧПУ.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Smarty. Может не стоит изобретать велосипед?

Comment: С чпу не знаком, может быть вы направите меня на хороший учебник по чпу?

Comment: ЧПУ здесь нипричем совершенно, шаблонизатор да подойдет, но есть ли в нем смысл ради двух полей?

Comment: Вы для начала полностью поясните что и на подобие чего вы хотите сделать, может, ЧПУ это так же не совсем то, чего вы ожидаете получить?

ЧПУ позволит вам обращаться к новостям, например вот так "http://site.ru/moya_novost_number_one.html" (или без html). Но для этого, естественно не обязательно создавать файл "moya_novost_number_one.html"

Comment: Ну кто говорил про два поля, я просто привел пример) В общем шаблонизатор если правильно прочитал, мне действительно подойдет

Comment: @dmitriy kiryushin, [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). один из самых популярных

Comment: @FLK, я - XSLT"ист, и если верить википедии верю в недостатки этого шаблонизатора, но выбирать каждому свое. (шутка как бы, отвечать не обязательно)

Comment: @Dex я не пользуюсь шаблонизаторами.. поэтому готов поверить вам )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слушай, если я правильно понял:
Я бы сделал так, в БД записывал новости, и был бы у меня один файл, который (с шаблоном уже) принимал GET-запросы
то есть подробней

> www.site.com/index.php?news=123

Вот он берет из БД новость с ID 123 и заполняет определенное поле для вывода новостей.
Ну и ЧПУ ещё...

Comment: Спасибо за эту мысль, наверное она мне больше пригодится чем возится с этими шаблонизаторами

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: @dmitriy kiryushin, шаблоны это несколько из другой темы, для этого вам и были заданы наводящие вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

в двух словах, создаем файл template.php это будет шаблон, в нужных местах указываем плейсхолдеры, к примеру для заголовка {header} для тела {body}. затем в php открываем этот файл и подставляем необходимые значения для заголовка и тела, затем сохраняем под нужным нам именем.